# Where to place composer scripts

Tags: php, composer-php

With composer scripts I can execute further commands for events like *pre-install-cmd* or *post-update-cmd*. There is a nice example here:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events

I just wonder where to place these composer scripts?

1. in a separate package
2. in /project_root/vendor/bin
3. in /project_root/scripts
4. somewhere else

With the first option I cannot execute the *pre-install-cmd*, can I? And how can I use the mentioned *ComposerScriptEvent* in a fresh project when Composer is not installed yet?

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,

Ralf